upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 last week, my crontab entries that play a short video (.asf) at different times, do not play if the display is locked
I checked my Power settings, ScreenBlank is set for 10 minutes, Automatic Suspend is Off,
PowerMode is Balanced.
When I unlock the Display lock via providing my password, I will have
all the crontab entries that were supposed to have run in the past 24 hours, run immediately.
So today, when I unlocked the display, 3 mplayer's popped up running 3 different short videos.
So the crontab entries are not skipped (that i know of), but are queued up for when the Display is unlocked.
Example crontab entry (with some edits):
00 13,16 * * 0-7 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 DISPLAY=:0 mplayer -volume 50 /directory path/my user name/Music/AVideo.asf
This has been working fine for years until this week after I upgraded from 22.04.x to 24.04.1

If the upgrade was a week ago how was it done? Did you get a prompt on the screen that a new version was available or did you force it?

upgrade was done on 8/31/2024 thru to 9/1/2024. It prompted me that the new 10.4.1 was available. The regular window prompt for the new LTS version that I always get every 2 years. It doesn't specify the version number but I think it just says distribution upgrade, etc.

Version 10.4.1 is not a Ubuntu version.

that should say 24.04.1 as in the original question.(sorry, not sure how that got typed out.)

God bless you for you diligence on this. I don't know what wayland is and would have never solved this regardless of the number of hours. I did what  Edu4rdM answered. I uncommented the wayland line in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, rebooted, changed DISPLAY to 1 in my crontab, locked terminal, and waited for my crontabs to kick off. Yup, the crontab entries running mplayer are running now while terminal is locked. Everything is back to how it was prior to upgrading to 24.04.1

I had the task which not run in crontab after upgrade Ubuntu 22.04.4 to Ubuntu 24.04.1

> DISPLAY=:0 timeout 30s /opt/FreeFileSync/Bin/RealTimeSync_x86_64
> "/home/admin/Desktop/task.ffs_real" >>
> $HOME/task_sync_log_file 2>&1


In logs I found this error:

Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?

I used this:

Checked the display


echo $DISPLAY


in my case it was :=0

Uncommented raw WaylandEnable=false


nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf


Rebooted server/workstation

Checked the display again



echo $DISPLAY


In my case it was changed from :=0 to :=1

Changed code


> DISPLAY=:1 timeout 30s /opt/FreeFileSync/Bin/RealTimeSync_x86_64
> "/home/admin/Desktop/task.ffs_real" >>
> $HOME/task_sync_log_file 2>&1


